# Does GeoServer and/or MapServer have a services directory similar to ArcGIS's services directory?

Tags: arcgis-server, geoserver, mapserver

Does GeoServer or MapServer have anything analogous to the [ArcGIS Server services directory](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/index.html)? Is there a convenient endpoint where you can see all the services hosted on a particular machine?

Edit:  I'm looking for the GeoServer or MapServer equivalent of this:  http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page (http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver/web/) in GeoServer gives links to all the capabilities documents for the server. I can't tell from the link you provided what exactly you want to find out.

Comment: Nice, I think that's it. Also, I see you're at PSU...I graduated from there in '04 with a BS in Geography...WE ARE!

Comment: This link is good, and could well be the current answer.  However, I still think what your asking can be done with MapServer/GeoServer, its just not been done yet.  See this post for some more info
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/esri-rest-api-clients/2771#2771

Answer (score 1):

Since ESRI have [opened up the specification](http://www.esri.com/news/releases/10_3qtr/geoservices-rest.html) behind the REST API, I have been keeping my ears peeled on when someone will create a similar REST structure plug-in for either Map/Geo-server.

Not heard of anything yet, but hopefully someone else knows more?

Comment: why would anyone want to do that? GeoServer and MapServer support international open standards to allow the interoperability of geospatial data. What would be the advantage to implementing ESRI's spec?

Comment: @iant- you could then use one API (albeit esri's...) to interact with  data served from both ArcGIS Server and other server side GIS packages.

Comment: Also means ESRI-Shop who maybe running esri-centric applications (any of the web APIs) could also easily leverage off Open Source alternatives such as MapServer/GeoServer.

Comment: But ESRI can manage WMS and WFS data already, again why go down a proprietary cul-de-sac when you can stay in the open?

Comment: And ESRI can change the spec any time that they want...